# Based on number of lines in uitextview getting substring

Tags: iphone, ios

Frrom UITextview i am able to get number of lines for given text, if its more than 4 lines i want to truncate the rest, so how to get the index to substring?

Comment: Could you show some code on what you have right now?

Comment: No coding. [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: I dont have any code right now.

Answer (score 1):

It will restrict to user to enter more than 4 lines in a UITextview

```
   - (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)aTextView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)aRange replacementText:(NSString*)aText
    {

        if (textView.contentSize.height/textView.font.lineHeight>4) {
            return NO;
        }
        else
            return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:textView.text];
static int numberOfLines = 0;
int nOC = 1;
while (nOC < [textView.text count] && numberOfLines < 4) {
    if ([[str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(nOC,1)] isEqualToString:@"\n"];  ) {
        numberOfLines++;
    }
    nOC++;
}

NSString *finalString = [str substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1,nOC)];
```

i hope this should work out for u. i calculated the number of characters till the 4th "\n" and used substringWithRange to extract the desired string. i didnt try this piece of code but this logic should work or at least assist u in your code. happy coding :)